# Android: can I put 2 Pendingintents on the same view?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I have an App Widget.

In the App Widget I try to set 2 Pendingintests on the same Viev:

```
        //FIRST PENDINGINTENT
        Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppWidget.class);
        i1.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        i1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, i1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //SECONDPENDINGINTENT
        Intent i11 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WakeUp.class);
        PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, i11,0);

        //I SET THE PENDINGINTENT ON THE VIEW
        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.background, pi1);
        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.background, pi);
```

As you can see I set 2 Pendingintents (**pi** and **pi1**) on the SAME view **R.id.background**.

The Pendingintent **pi** works as it shuould.

The Pendingintent **pi1** has NO EFFECT.

Please any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Any `View` in the `RemoteViews` can have only one `PendingIntent` for `setOnClickPendingIntent()`. If you call `setOnClickPendingIntent()` twice, the last one in wins.

Hence, please call it just once, and have `WakeUp` call `sendBroadcast()` to accomplish your second operation.

Also, please replace `getApplicationContext()` with `this`, as you do not need the application context in any of this code.